# How i can save json data into database and to foreach after save?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-nestable

Hello developers I'm working on a categories tree list and want to save it into the database
I use this project from GitHub https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable

How I can save this data into the database?

```
[{"id":13},{"id":14},{"id":15,"children":[{"id":16},{"id":17},{"id":18}]}]
```

[image: Image of the list]

Comment: Your question is too broad. Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Front-End :
Through event listeners pass this data to the server as a query string.

Back-End :
Fetch the query string from server using POST method.
Convert the fetched data into the format acceptable to database (depends upon the framework and database used ).